# Base operator called instead of Derived one - Normal behaviour?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

As I'm currently playing with C++, I come up to an issue. Code below:

```
#include        <iostream>

class Base {
public:
  virtual ~Base()                   {}


  virtual Base&         operator=(const Base& o)
  {
    std::cout << "Base operator called" << std::endl;
    return *this;
  }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
  virtual ~Derived() {}

  virtual Base&         operator=(const Base& o)

  {
    std::cout << "Derived operator called" << std::endl;
    return *this;
  }
};

int     main(void)
{
  Derived       a;
  Derived       b;
  Base&         c = a;
  Base&         d = b;

  a = b;                        // Base called                                                                                                                                 
  a = static_cast<Base>(b);     // Derived called                                                                                                                              
  a = d;                        // Derived called                                                                                                                              
  c = d;                        // Derived called                                                                                                                              
  return (0);
}
```

The comment show what output I get.
The last 3 results are very much predictable, but I can't understand the first.

As shown in the second one (static_cast), Derived::operator= is called when the right operand is a Base class. However, g++ (4.5.3-r2, gentoo Linux) success to understand that it must use the 'Base' class, but doesn't go down the inheritance tree.

So I was expecting either Derived::operator= to be called, or g++ complaining for no "Derived&  Derived::operator=(const Derived&)". Could someone explain this behaviour to me ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a **compiler generated** copy-assignment, i.e `operator=(Derived &)` in `Derived` class, because `Derived::operator=(Base const&)` is **not** copy-assignment for `Derived`. This **does not** prevent compiler from generating the  copy-assignment if you use assignment in your code.

So this line:

```
 a = b;  // Base called
```

calls the compiler generated `operator=(Derived &)` for `Derived` class, which then calls the `operator=(Base const&)`. Hence `Base called` is printed.

Experiment:  add this to `Derived` class:

```
Derived & operator=(Derived const & obj) : Base(obj)
{
   std::cout << "copy-assignment called" << std::endl;
   return *this;
}
```

Now, `a=b` will cause to print this:

> Base called
>   copy-assignment called

Note the *order* of printing also.

Hope that clarify your doubt.

---

Now this,

```
a = static_cast<Base>(b);  /// Derived called
```

is functionally equivalent to this:

```
Base ___generated_tmp = static_cast<Base>(b);
a = ___generated_tmp;
```

means, `a = ___generated_tmp` calls `operator=(Base const&)`, as the type of `___generated_tmp` is `Base`.

And the rest two are pretty much clear, as you already seem to know.

Comment: Oh stupid me, yeah I forget the compiler generated operator. So I just added an overload in my project and everything did work. Thanks!